# Jetty "OPTIONS=All" migration to Jetty 9 modules

Tags: jetty

Jetty versions before version 9.1 have an [`OPTIONS` argument](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Start_Options).
Jetty versions from version 9.1 have a [*module* system](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-modules.html).

What is the Jetty 9.1 module equivalent to `OPTIONS=All`?

Comment: `OPTIONS=All` means many different things to many different people.  What does it mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be answered as-is, as you haven't specified what "OPTIONS=All" means to you.

Here's what it means from Jetty `8.1.13.v20130916`

```
$ java -jar start.jar OPTIONS=All --version
Active Options: [All, Server, annotations, ext, jmx, jsp, plus, resources, websocket]
Version Information on 39 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the OPTIONS=[option,option,...] command line option will be reflected here.
 0:                (dir) | ${jetty.home}/resources
 1:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
 2:  3.0.0.v201112011016 | ${jetty.home}/lib/servlet-api-3.0.jar
 3:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
 4:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-continuation-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
 5:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
 6:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
 7:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
 8:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
 9:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-deploy-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
10:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlets-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
11:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-rewrite-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
12:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jmx-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
13:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-ajp-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
14:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jndi-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
15:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-plus-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
16:  1.1.0.v201105071233 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar
17:  1.4.1.v201005082020 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar
18:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-annotations-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
19:  1.1.0.v201108011116 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-1.1.0.v201108011116.jar
20:  3.1.0.v200803061910 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/org.objectweb.asm-3.1.0.v200803061910.jar
21:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-policy-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
22:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-client-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
23:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-websocket-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
24:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-overlay-deployer-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
25:                1.1.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jta/javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar
26:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/spdy/spdy-core-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
27:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/spdy/spdy-jetty-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
28:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/spdy/spdy-jetty-http-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
29:  2.2.0.v201108011116 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/com.sun.el-2.2.0.v201108011116.jar
30:  2.2.0.v201108011116 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.el-2.2.0.v201108011116.jar
31:  1.2.0.v201105211821 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar
32:  2.2.0.v201112011158 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar
33:  2.2.2.v201112011158 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar
34:  1.2.0.v201112081803 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v201112081803.jar
35: 3.7.0.M20110909-1335 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.1.jar
36:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/monitor/jetty-monitor-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
37:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
38:     8.1.13.v20130916 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-8.1.13.v20130916.jar
```

That just enables the classpath for all other options declared in Jetty's embeddded `start.config` (a concept since removed in Jetty 9.1).  The use of `OPTIONS=All` does not enable the use of those classes, that requires XML declarations and properties to also be defined, in the correct order (no less).

The use of `OPTIONS=All` also does not represent all of the jars and classes that ships with Jetty.  Some Jetty distributions also have jdbc, xa, jta, cdi, jms, and cometd that are not picked up by `OPTIONS=All` but rather specific entries like `OPTIONS=All,jms`.  Then you also have specific configuration for SSL, and NPN+SPDY that are not simply picked up with a simple `OPTIONS=All`

With Jetty 9.1 and the module system you have classpath + xml configuration + properties all in one.  Enable a module and you get the rest.

With Jetty 9.1 you also have many more features than Jetty 8, so saying "I want it all" is also irrelevant.  However, if you are saying "I want the same feature set in Jetty 9.1 that I had in Jetty 8.1 if I enabled all classpath entries with manually defined XML entries in my start.ini" then this is the equivalent.

Presented in the form of a `${jetty.base}`.

Make an empty directory for your `${jetty.base}`

```
[joakim]$ cd jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115
[jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115]$ mkdir my-base
[jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115]$ cd my-base/
```

Initialize it:

This quickstart step will:

1. build out a `start.ini` suitable for you
2. creating any directories that the module might need
3. download any artifacts that you might need (such as the sample keystore, and the npn jar)

*This is not a required step, you can create / edit / manage the `start.ini` and base directory completely manually and totally on your own if you want.*

This command is equivalent to most of the same features that you had in Jetty 8.

```
[my-base]$ java -jar ../start.jar --add-to-start=ext,resources,jsp,continuation,rewrite,proxy,monitor,stats,ipaccess,jmx,requestlog,logging,https,http,webapp,annotations,websocket,spdy
WARNING: ext             initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: ext             enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/lib
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/lib/ext
WARNING: resources       initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: resources       enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/resources
WARNING: jsp             initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: jsp             enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: continuation    initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: continuation    enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: rewrite         initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: rewrite         enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: proxy           initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: proxy           enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: monitor         initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: monitor         enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: stats           initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: stats           enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: ipaccess        initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: ipaccess        enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: jmx             initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: jmx             enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: requestlog      initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: requestlog      enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/logs
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: logging         initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: logging         enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: https           initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: https           enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: ssl             initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: ssl             enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
DOWNLOAD: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/plain/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/keystore to etc/keystore
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: http            initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: http            enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: webapp          initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: webapp          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: annotations     initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: annotations     enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: websocket       initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: websocket       enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: annotations     enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: spdy            initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: spdy            enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: ssl             enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
WARNING: npn             initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
WARNING: npn             enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
DOWNLOAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/npn/npn-boot/1.1.6.v20130911/npn-boot-1.1.6.v20130911.jar to lib/npn/npn-boot-1.1.6.v20130911.jar
```

You can see what this configuration looks like by viewing the `start.ini` or simply by asking Jetty to `--list-config`

```
[my-base]$ java -jar ../start.jar --list-config

Java Environment:
-----------------
 java.home=/opt/java/jdk-7u45-x64/jre
 java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
 java.vm.version=24.45-b08
 java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
 java.vm.info=mixed mode
 java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
 java.runtime.version=1.7.0_45-b18
 java.io.tmpdir=/tmp


Jetty Environment:
-----------------
 jetty.home=/home/joakim/jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115
 jetty.base=/home/joakim/jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115/my-base
 jetty.version=9.1.0.v20131115

JVM Arguments:
--------------
 -Xbootclasspath/p:lib/npn/npn-boot-1.1.6.v20130911.jar

System Properties:
------------------
 jetty.base = /home/joakim/jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115/my-base
 jetty.home = /home/joakim/jetty-distribution-9.1.0.v20131115

Properties:
-----------
 http.timeout = 30000
 https.port = 8443
 https.timeout = 30000
 jetty.dump.start = false
 jetty.dump.stop = false
 jetty.keymanager.password = OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g
 jetty.keystore = etc/keystore
 jetty.keystore.password = OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4
 jetty.port = 8080
 jetty.secure.port = 8443
 jetty.truststore = etc/keystore
 jetty.truststore.password = OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4
 spdy.port = 8443
 spdy.timeout = 30000
 threads.max = 200
 threads.min = 10
 threads.timeout = 60000

Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 45 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
 0:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-client-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
 1:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-continuation-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
 2:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jmx-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
 3:                    (dir) | ${jetty.base}/resources
 4:                    3.1.0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar
 5:                  3.1.RC0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
 6:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
 7:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
 8:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
 9:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
10:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
11:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
12:      1.1.0.v201105071233 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar
13:      1.4.1.v201005082020 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar
14:                      1.2 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
15:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-rewrite-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
16:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
17:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
18:                    3.0.0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.el-3.0.0.jar
19:      1.2.0.v201105211821 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar
20:                    2.3.2 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar
21:                    2.3.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1.jar
22:                    2.3.3 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/jetty-jsp-jdt-2.3.3.jar
23:      1.2.0.v201112081803 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v201112081803.jar
24:   3.8.2.v20130121-145325 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
25:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-plus-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
26:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-proxy-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
27:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/spdy/spdy-client-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
28:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/spdy/spdy-core-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
29:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/spdy/spdy-http-common-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
30:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/spdy/spdy-http-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
31:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/spdy/spdy-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
32:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
33:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-annotations-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
34:                      4.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-4.1.jar
35:                      4.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-commons-4.1.jar
36:                      1.2 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
37:                      1.0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar
38:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
39:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
40:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-api-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
41:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-client-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
42:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-common-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
43:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
44:          9.1.0.v20131115 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-servlet-9.1.0.v20131115.jar

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-jmx.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-logging.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-ipaccess.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-monitor.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-requestlog.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-rewrite.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-ssl.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-stats.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-https.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-plus.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-proxy.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-spdy.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-annotations.xml
```

Comment: Went ahead and filed an enhancement request for Jetty 9.1 for this - https://bugs.eclipse.org/424390